# Custom fonts on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

On iOS 14 custom fonts aren't loading properly. On iOS 13 works just fine. Does Apple make changes on installing custom fonts, or where can be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No Apple did not make changes for adding custom fonts in iOS 14.

- Make sure your font files are added to your app target.
- Make sure each font is listed under the custom fonts entry in your info.plist file.